# Issue After upgrading Restsharp version

Tags: c#, .net, post, restsharp

Can someone please help on this issue, i gets hang and no error is coming.
Seems like ends up with some unknow issue.
I am attaching my code before and after upgrading the restsharp library.

Code in Rest sharp version 106.12.00

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://shoonyatrade.finvasia.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            var body = @"jData={""apkversion"":""1.0.0"",""uid"":""123456""}";
            request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Code after upgrading to 108.0.1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://shoonyatrade.finvasia.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth");
            client.Options.MaxTimeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest("",Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            var body = @"jData={""apkversion"":""1.0.0"",""uid"":""123456""}";
            request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Expected Response

```
{"stat":"Not_Ok","emsg":"Invalid Input :  uid or pwd or factor2 or imei or apkversion or vc or appkey or source is Missing."}
```

Postman Authorisation
[image]

Postman Headers
[image]

PostMan Results (Expected)

[image]

Comment: Read notes on following page : https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107

Comment: hi,
i have tried AddStringBody. AddJsonBody is for serializable objects.

Comment: Also see following : https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases  I do not think the connection is completing.  If response null?  What status code is in the response?

Comment: @jdweng: Connection is working well attached Postman API call for your reference.

Comment: From Postman it looks like an id is missing.  Requests that work in Postman don't always work in c#.  The HTTP headers are sometimes different of cookies are not the same.  You could delete cookies and then try both methods again.  Better to use a sniffer like WireShark or Fiddler and see if you are getting a response.

Comment: Looks like your Body parameters need to be HTTP Header as stated in following : https://restsharp.dev/v107/#body-parameters.  This line needs to be fixed : var body = @"jData={""apkversion"":""1.0.0"",""uid"":""123456""}";

Comment: Hi @jdweng,,

Have tried the same now after u suggested getting same issue.
can u please try to re generate the same at my side when request is executed it gets hang.

Comment: There can be lots of difference.  Better to show the postman results.

Comment: The result which is shown in above image is perfect. My problem is I am not able to execute the same in c# with restsharp I getting 400 and result as Not ok that is ok for me.

Comment: C# code gets hang when request is executed that is the issue result I will manage.

Comment: You are missing an authenticator.  I think the ID is the authenticator but not sure which method you are using.  See : https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html#basic-authentication

Comment: Added Postman authentication details and header details. when replicated same is c# ressharp is causes hang.

Comment: See following : https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line solved my issue

**System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;**

I have used **fiddler** to understand what actual request is going on web.

```
using RestSharp;
using System;

using System.Net.Http;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            var client = new RestClient("https://shoonyatrade.finvasia.com/NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth");
            var request = new RestRequest("",Method.Post);
            var body = @"jData={""apkversion"":""1.0.0"",""uid"":""123456""}";
            request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set the option globally, `Expect100Continue` is also a property of `RestClientOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

The docs [clearly say](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#body-parameters) that you should not use `AddParameter` with content-type as the parameter name. It won't work.

Use `AddStringBody` as [described in the docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#request-body).

```
request.AddStringBody(body, "text/plain);
```

You would spend way less time figuring out what's wrong by sending requests to something like requestbin.com and analysing the actual content of it.

Comment: var url = "https://shoonyatrade.finvasia.com/";
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.Options.MaxTimeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(url+"NorenWClientTP/QuickAuth/", Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            var body = @"jData={""apkversion"":""1.0.0"",""uid"":""123456""}";
            request.AddStringBody(body,"text/plain");
            RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: As I wrote, trace the request and you'll see what is different compared with the one in Postman

Comment: hi @Alexey,
Compared in fiddler the request header is same.
It is not able to capture the response when the request gets posted it goes and after some time it gives time-out exception.

Comment: Another thing notice is same works with .Net core when run in c# console with .net frame work it has this issue.