# Token Autorization in RestSharp does not appear

Tags: c#

Good morning, I'm retrieving an authorization token using RestSharp, but instead of returning a Token, it returns an html page:
`var client = new RestClient("https://iam.efatura.cv/auth/realms/taxpayers/ protocol/openid- connect/auth"); var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);     request.AddHeader("grant_type", "authorization_code"); request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json"); request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=adadasdasdasdasda& scope=openid&clientSecretasdadsdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasasd& redirect_uri=https://iam.efatura.cv/auth/realms/taxpayers", ParameterType.RequestBody); IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); Token=response.Content;`

Comment: What is the status code?  Had similar question last week the latest version of RestSharp requires the id to be in a header and not in body.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760702/issue-after-upgrading-restsharp-version#comment130249080_73760702

Comment: the status code is OK

Comment: Is this MVC framework with ajax? If so, you're getting the redirect html as a response. You're failing somewhere in the process and MVC is doing its thing.

Comment: Yu may have a cookie and request is using a cookie.  You would have to delete the cookie to a new token.

Comment: I went to see if there is any kokiee there is not with  cod response.Cookies.Count.ToString() return 0,